# Angular Carousel-like Slide In/Out Animation

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I am trying to implement an image gallery component in Angular and stuck at a particular point of animating the image transition. When I click left or right buttons, the animation works properly, however when the direction is changed from left to right or right to left, the transition is not as expected, and it looks like the old image is sliding into the opposite direction. There should not be an unexpected transition when direction is changed.

StackBlitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-exsdas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Here is the code:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger("slideInOut", [
      transition("void => *", [
          style({ transform: "translateX({{start}}100%)" }),
          animate("0.3s ease-out", style({ transform: "translateX(0)" }))
      ]),
      transition("* => void", [
          style({ transform: "translateX(0)" }),
          animate("0.3s ease-out", style({ transform: "translateX({{end}}100%)" }))
      ])
    ])
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  activeIndex = 0;
  images = [
    { 
      name: 'Image 1',
      url: 'https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/q2/wallhaven-q28v7r.jpg',
    },
    {
      name: 'Image 2',
      url: 'https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/zm/wallhaven-zmwqdo.jpg'
    },
    {
      name: 'Image 3',
      url: 'https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/76/wallhaven-76l5r9.jpg'
    }
  ];
  lastDirection: 'left' | 'right' | 'none' = 'none';

  public onNavigate(dir: 'left' | 'right'): void {
    this.lastDirection = dir;
    switch (dir) {
      case 'left':
        if (this.activeIndex === 0) {
          this.activeIndex = this.images.length - 1;
        } else {
          this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex - 1;
        }
        break;
      case 'right':
        if (this.activeIndex === this.images.length - 1) {
          this.activeIndex = 0;
        } else {
          this.activeIndex = this.activeIndex + 1;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ul class="image-list">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index">
    <li
      *ngIf="i === activeIndex"
      [@.disabled]="lastDirection === 'none'"
      [@slideInOut]="{
        value: '',
        params: {
          start: lastDirection === 'right' ? '+' : '-',
          end: lastDirection === 'right' ? '-' : '+'
        }
      }"
    >
      <img [src]="image.url" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
      <div>{{ image.name }}</div>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
<button style="margin-right: 10px;" (click)="onNavigate('left')">Left</button>
<button (click)="onNavigate('right')">Right</button>
```

**app.component.css**

```
ul.image-list {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 320px;
  width: 480px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

ul.image-list li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.